# First Order Logic and equivalence rules

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

I have a couple of questions about first order logic equivalence rules.

- How do you distribute the $\neg$ correctly with the $\exists$ and $\forall$ quantifiers? If let's say I have $$\neg[\forall x\;A(x)\;\lor B(y)]$$ Does it become:$$\neg\forall x\;\neg A(x)\land\neg B(y)$$?
- In something like this:
  $$\forall c\; A(c)\Rightarrow B(c)$$
  Is this equivalent to:
  $$\neg [\forall c\;A(c)]\lor B(c)$$
  Or:
  $$\forall c\; \neg A(c)\lor B(c)$$?
- For the rule $\neg\forall x\;p\equiv \exists x\;\neg p$, is $p$ *all* the predicates that contain $x$? Let's say I have:
  $$\neg[\neg\forall\,c\; A(c, Something)]\lor [\exists\,d\; B(d, SomethingElse)\land \neg C(c, d)]$$Will this yield:$$\neg[\exists\,c\; \neg A(c, Something)]\lor [\exists\,d\; B(d, SomethingElse)\land \neg C(c, d)]$$ Or will I have to move the $\neg$ on the entire statement since $C(c,d)$ is dependent on $c$?

The professor I have didn't explain this very well. I appreciate any help.

Comment: The first is wrong: too many $\lnot$ and you have forgotten De Morgan...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Fixed De Morgan's but too many $\neg$?

Comment: ¬[∀xA(x)∨B(y)] by De Morgan is equivalent to ¬∀xA(x)∧¬B(y).

Comment: For the rule ¬∀xp≡∃x¬p, it is not a predicate but the sub-formula being the scope of the quantifier. The correct writing is ¬∀x(...) where in place of the dots you may have a "complex" formula. Thus, you have to proceed step-by-step; first ∃x¬(...) and then consider the part ¬(...). If there is a new quantifier, apply again the quantifier rules; if not, go on (if needed) with propositional equivalences, like De Morgan.

Answer (score 1):

$$\neg\Bigl[\bigl(\forall x\;A(x)\bigr)\lor B(y)\Bigr] \\
\bigl(\neg\forall x\;A(x)\bigr)\land \neg B(y)\\
\bigl(\exists x\;\neg A(x)\bigr)\land \neg B(y)$$
or perhaps you mean
$$\neg\Bigl[\forall x\;\bigl(A(x)\lor B(y)\bigr)\Bigr] \\
\exists x\;\neg\bigl(A(x)\lor B(y)\bigr)\\
\exists x\;\bigl(\neg A(x)\land\neg B(y)\bigr)$$

And
$$\forall c\;\bigl(A(c)\to B(c)\bigr) $$
is equivalent to 
$$\forall c\;\bigl(\neg A(c)\lor B(c)\bigr) $$
whereas 
$$\bigl(\forall c\;A(c)\bigr)\to B(c) $$
(which has some weird concept of free and bound variable use) would be equivalent to
$$\neg\bigl(\forall c\;A(c)\bigr)\lor B(c) $$
or 
$$\bigl(\exists c\;\neg A(c)\bigr)\lor B(c) $$

Answer (score 0):

$\lnot[\forall x\;P(x)] $ is equivalent to $\exists x \; \lnot P(x)$. Now use
De Morgan on $A(x) \lor B(x)$.

$\lnot [ A(x) \lor B(x) ] $ is equivalent to $ ((\lnot A(x)) \land  (\lnot B(x))$.

Comment: Is $P(x)=A(x)\lor B(x)$?

Comment: @user332043Z: In this case yes, the point is to do one step at a time.